# Android: Running a time-out timer under screen rotation

Tags: android, timer, rotation

I's like my Android app to close down after a period of disuse.  Without screen rotation, I've easily implemented a solution with Timer/TimerTask.  Alas, when the screen rotates, everything is (understandably) messed up.

The time out period is typically 10 minutes and the user has to be able to reset the clock to zero at anytime, invoking another 10 minute period.

So what's the preferred approach to do the timing in the background, be able to reset the clock, and ultimately receive a shutdown notice,  despite an occasional screen rotation?  I've looked at IntentService, but don't see how to reset the clock, or know the preferred way of getting the shutdown notice back.  And everything must be set up so that access to the timer is available after the app reconstruction on rotation.

Thanks,

Chris

Comment: How about a Service and then use a Broadcast to notify the Activity. 
Service runs in the background independent of the Activity, and your Activity registers itself as a listener to the Broadcast.

Comment: `everything is (understandably) messed up` not understandable at all.  About 1,000,000 apps in the Play store work just fine.  You are saving the timer state in onPause() and reloading it in onResume()?

Comment: How do I save the java.util.Timer state?  It's not parcellable, is it?

Comment: An IntentService seems feasible, however, there's no way I can see to stop the service (see many discussions here.)  I think a plain Service has the same problem.